# server socket error timer management

Tags: python-2.7, sockets

There is a server for a single client. Client can connect and disconnect at any time
Here is simplified code

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
while true:
    a = s.accept()
    try:
        data = a[0].recv(1024)
    except socket.error:
        a[0].close()
        print 'cought the error'
```

It works, but socket.error generation takes random amount of time from few seconds up to a minute. May this value be managed?

Comment: Not directly. Search for non-blocking I/O or select/poll related documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If the client disconnects, there is no `socket.error`, rather `recv()` returns an empty string immediately. Besides, you are not closing the connection in this case.